# Use node-fetch v2.6 to get HTML of a website

Tags: javascript, node-fetch

Currently my code is the following:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

(async function () {
  console.log(await fetch("https://a.website.in-ht.ml"));
})()
```

However, It is only returning data on the website, as opposed to the HTML. Anyone know what the issue may be?

(As the title says, I am using v2.6 not 3.0+)

Comment: Did you try looking at the _body_ of the response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

(async function () {
  const res = await fetch("https://a.website.in-ht.ml")
  const html = await res.text()
  console.log(html)
})()
```

This takes the text response instead of the full response.

Comment: `TypeError: res.body.text is not a function`
Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry about that. It should just be res.text(). I fixed it now.